# How to assign a variable to the variables decalred with <gmp.h>

Tags: c++, c++17, gmp

I recently used a library `<gmp.h>` and I am having difficulty assigning a value to the variable `mpf_t x` I declared. I used `mpf_init2 (x,256)` to initialize it and when I do `x=1.234029187340918239082372984509283475029845702` 
I get

```
highprecision.cc:7:7: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘double’ to ‘mpf_t’ {aka ‘__mpf_struct [1]’}
    7 |     x=1.234029187340918239082372984509283475029845702;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

this error. Any idea why? I am using C++17 GCC btw. The documentary is also very confusing. Sorry.

Comment: https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html for the official C++ wrapper that you'll find easier to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mpf_set_d(x, 1.234029187340918239082372984509283475029845702);
```

Maybe reading the documentation would help?

BTW if you think you are going to get 256 digits of precision in a `double` literal you are mistaken. `1.234029187340918239082372984509283475029845702` is still going to have the regular precision of a double on your system (around 17 to 19 digits usually).

Comment: then how can i get x to be 1.234029187340918239082372984509283475029845702?

Comment: I believe you can set it from a string `mpf_set_str(x, "1.234029187340918239082372984509283475029845702e0", 10);` although I'm not that experienced with the `mpf` functions. At least by using a string instead of a double GMP has all the information needed.